# Apache shutdown unexpectedly , Não Funciona/Inicia!

Tags: apache, xampp

Meu **xampp**
  não inicia mais o **Apache**, isso está me impossibilitando de testar meus códigos, eu estava programando, estava tudo funcionando normalmente quando do nada meu **Apache** para de funcionar e toda vez que eu o executo ele dá o mesmo erro, já tentei reiniciar o pc, mas não deu resultado,segue o erro

> Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
>   11:01:34  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
>   11:01:34  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>   11:01:34  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>   11:01:34  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>   11:01:34  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
>   11:01:34  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Não sei oque fazer, alguém me ajuda!

Comment: Esta rodando o Skype junto? Alguma coisa esta utilizando a mesma porta que o seu apache, dai quando ele tenta iniciar não funciona.

Comment: Não eu já tentei finalizar o skype, além diso estava funcionando antes aconteceu do nada ;-;

Comment: Nikk, verifique se as portas que o seu apache usa estão liberadas no seu Firewall.
Um teste que você pode fazer é desabilitar o firewall e testar para ver se ele vai iniciar.

Comment: O firewall já se encontra desabilitado nesse momento ;-;

Comment: Você pode entrar no php.ini e tentar mudar a porta do apache tipo para 8080, caso não encontre o que esta bloqueando. Aconselho a entrar nas configurações do skype e mudar a porta que ele utiliza, só para ter certeza

Comment: okay vou tentar as duas coisas

Comment: Nikk este erro está sendo gerado por bloqueio de portas, se o Firewall esta desabilitado verifique se tem algum anti-virus bloqueando o acesso. Se o usuário(conta) que você esta usando possui os privilégios necessários para executar o programa.

Comment: Veja qual é o erro que aparece no log de erros do Apache.

Comment: @JoaoAbiSaber Como já falei ele funcionava antes, então não tem haver com permissão e eu não tenho nenhum antivirus Executado nesse momento

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti Não aparece nada o error log

Comment: Gente, eu mudei o port do apache para 8080, e apareceu outro erro diferente, mas eu já achei a resposta do outro erro obrigado a todos pela ajuda

Comment: Pra quem quiser saber como resolvi após ter trocado o port  segue o erro e a resposta do SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558410/xampp-port-80-in-use-by-unable-to-open-process-with-pid-4-12  é a primeira resposta